# why mysql explain show using index prefer bigint column than int column

Tags: mysql, indexing, int, bigint

Recently ,i got on a strange question,my test table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `index_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `card_no` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `card_no2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `optype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `optype2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  `_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_a` (`a`),
  KEY `idx_card_no` (`card_no`),
  KEY `idx_card_no2` (`card_no2`),
  KEY `idx_optype` (`optype`),
  KEY `idx_optype2` (`optype2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

5 major columns,a varchar,cardno and cardno2 are bigint,optype and optype2 are int,
as my experience,**mysql index prefer select high cardinality、small data type and non null columns**,but when i run explain query statements,a few problems occurred,here is my init data procedure

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`xx`@`%` PROCEDURE `simple_insert`( )
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

  my_loop: LOOP
    SET counter=counter+1;

    IF counter=10000 THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `index_test` (`a`,`card_no`,`card_no2`,`optype`,`optype2`, `create_time`) VALUES (replace(uuid(), '-', ''),counter,counter%180, counter,counter%180,current_timestamp);

  END LOOP my_loop;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

insert 10,000 row data,first  i execute the statistics query

```
select * from information_schema.statistics where table_schema = 'test' and table_name = 'index_test';
```

output

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_SCHEMA | INDEX_NAME   | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
| def           | test         | index_test |          0 | test         | PRIMARY      |            1 | id          | A         |       10089 |     NULL | NULL   |          | BTREE      |         |               |
| def           | test         | index_test |          1 | test         | idx_a        |            1 | a           | A         |        9999 |     NULL | NULL   |          | BTREE      |         |               |
| def           | test         | index_test |          1 | test         | idx_card_no  |            1 | card_no     | A         |        9999 |     NULL | NULL   |          | BTREE      |         |               |
| def           | test         | index_test |          1 | test         | idx_card_no2 |            1 | card_no2    | A         |         180 |     NULL | NULL   |          | BTREE      |         |               |
| def           | test         | index_test |          1 | test         | idx_optype   |            1 | optype      | A         |        9999 |     NULL | NULL   |          | BTREE      |         |               |
| def           | test         | index_test |          1 | test         | idx_optype2  |            1 | optype2     | A         |         180 |     NULL | NULL   |          | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

step 2:

```
explain select * from index_test where  optype=9600 and a= 'e095af180f4911ea8d907036bd142a99';
```

output:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | index_test | NULL       | ref  | idx_a,idx_optype | idx_a | 194     | const |    1 |     5.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

as my experience ,varchar(64) space is bigger than int,so use int column is ok

step3:

```
explain select * from index_test where  optype=9600 and card_no = 9600;
```

output

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys          | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | index_test | NULL       | ref  | idx_card_no,idx_optype | idx_card_no | 8       | const |    1 |     5.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

so ,the question is **why mysql query optimizer prefer use bigint column than int column**,any one can help me or give some offcinal document links about this question ,thanks。

by the way,my test environment is macos(10.14.6) x64 and mysql server version is 5.7.26

Comment: In order to make questtion more accuracy, i adjust table name and step output, in this case,i am not discuss mysql **left-prefix rules**,**just only mysql query optimizer index select order(which index is the best for this query)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `INT` vs `BIGINT` is the issue.  First, let me mention *better* indexes:

For

```
where  optype=9600 and a= 'e095af180f4911ea8d907036bd142a99'
```

*Either* of these "composite" indexes would be optimal, and better than what you have:

```
INDEX(optype, a)
INDEX(a, optype)
```

For

```
where  optype=9600
  and card_no = 9600
  and  a= 'e095af180f4911ea8d907036bd142a99'
```

any index starting with those 3 columns is optimal; any 2 would be "good", and single-column indexes would be poor, but better than no index.

The optimizer may be making probes to see which of your 3 poor indexes is best.

I can't explain why it did not list `a` as a "Possible key".

Comment: composite index actualy is perhaps the best index,but in this case,i just create three index for test purpose(three single column index) and the query is also test for mysql query optimizer **"which is the best way for  data query"** ,as i mentioned "mysql index prefer select high cardinality、small data type and non null columns",so i just create few same column **data type(int ,bigint varchar)** and **different column cardinality**,just for test purpose

Comment: @guanzhisong - When adding more indexes, keep in mind that `INDEX(x,y)` obviates the need for `INDEX(x)`.  See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql